# Django elasticsearch-dsl updating M2M on pre_save

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using the django-elasticsearch-dsl package and am having a little bit of a dilemma. Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Source(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Posting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sources = models.ManyToMany(Sources, related_name="postings", through="PostingSource")

class PostingSource(models.Model):
    posting = models.ForeignKey(Posting, related_name="posting_sources", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, related_name="posting_sources", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**documents.py**

```
class PostingDocument(Document):
    sources = fields.ObjectField(properties={"name": fields.KeywordField()})

    class Index:
        name = "posting"
        settings = {"all the settings stuff"}

    class Django:
        model = Posting
        fields = ["title"]
        related_models = [PostingSource]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related("sources")

    def get_instance_from_related(self, related_instance):
        if isinstance(related_instance, PostingSource):
            return related_instance.posting
```

My issue is, when I update the sources on the posting, for some reason, the elasticsearch index is updated pre_save and not post_save. I basically have to do a put request 2 times with the same sources in order for the changes to reflect in my index. I added a `def prepare_sources(self, instance):` as part of my document and it seems to work, but it feels like it will cause performance issues later. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple months of testing, I solved my first question by adding a `def prepare_sources(self, instance):` where I denormalize my many to many relationship. I also sort of solved my second question by simply having the `.select_related("sources")` which helps with performance.